# Circular Progress bar with three different color in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

I want to create circular progress bar with three different color in it. I am only able to achieve two colors but I am not able to achieve three colors so i want  to know that is it possible in progress bar. Simply I want three processes to be done with three different color. Here is my code for two different color in progressbar.

```
     private HoloCircularProgressBar mHoloCircularProgressBarCount
        mHoloCircularProgressBarCount = (HoloCircularProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.holoCircularProgressBar2);
                mHoloCircularProgressBarCount.setMarkerEnabled(false);
                // mHoloCircularProgressBar1.setMarkerProgress(0f);
                mHoloCircularProgressBarCount.setProgressColor(malecolor);

                mHoloCircularProgressBarCount.setProgressBackgroundColor(femalecolor);
                mHoloCircularProgressBarCount.setProgress(0.5f);
    ...
    ...
    ...
animate(mHoloCircularProgressBarCount, null, maleratio / 100, 1000);
```

Comment: Sure its possible.  Write it from scratch and do the canvas draws yourself.  Its maybe 45 minutes worth of programming.

Comment: Yaa but havent done it anytime. Appreciate it if you send some links.

Comment: Sounds like a great time to learn.  Here's some info on making a custom view in general:  http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: @mohammedalisunasara check this https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar if ithelps

Comment: Thanks but i want circular progress bar with three processes with three dynamic colors...